# Spring-boot application won't boot at startup inside docker

Tags: java, spring, docker, spring-boot, digital-ocean

I am running a simple spring-boot application inside a docker container. At startup whether started with  `java -jar MY_JAR.jar` or `mvn spring-boot:run` the application will always hang at the following point:

```
2014-12-22 23:26:58.957  INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
```

Here's the catch, I can ONLY reproduce this on an Ubuntu 14.04 box in DigitalOcean (1CPU, 1GB MEM), even though it's running inside a container. On my local machine (mac) everything runs fine.

**The Dockerfile:**

```
FROM java:8
ADD target/MY_SERVICE-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar /data/svc.jar
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["java", "-jar", "/data/svc.jar"]
```

**Things I've Tried**

- Give JVM more memory (75% of machine total)
- Intstalling the `haveged` library as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25660899/spring-boot-actuator-application-wont-start-on-ubuntu-vps)
- Every other version of java I could get my hands on

Any suggestions?

Thanks for any help.

**The whole log** (started with --debug):

```
[Text Art Omitted]

 :: Spring Boot ::       (v1.1.10.RELEASE)

2014-12-22 19:22:58.375  INFO 20816 --- [           main] com.spectrom.uploadService.Main          : Starting Main on spectrom-services with PID 20816 (/root/spectrom-upload-service/target/upload-service-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar started by root in /root/spectrom-upload-service)
2014-12-22 19:22:58.392 DEBUG 20816 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Loading source class com.spectrom.uploadService.Main
2014-12-22 19:22:58.671 DEBUG 20816 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.c.ConfigFileApplicationListener  : Skipped config file 'file:./config/application.yaml' resource not found
2014-12-22 19:22:58.673 DEBUG 20816 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.c.ConfigFileApplicationListener  : Skipped config file 'file:./config/application.properties' resource not found
2014-12-22 19:22:58.674 DEBUG 20816 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.c.ConfigFileApplicationListener  : Skipped config file 'file:./config/application.yml' resource not found
2014-12-22 19:22:58.675 DEBUG 20816 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.c.ConfigFileApplicationListener  : Skipped config file 'file:./application.yaml' resource not found
2014-12-22 19:22:58.675 DEBUG 20816 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.c.ConfigFileApplicationListener  : Skipped config file 'file:./application.properties' resource not found
2014-12-22 19:22:58.676 DEBUG 20816 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.c.ConfigFileApplicationListener  : Skipped config file 'file:./application.yml' resource not found
2014-12-22 19:22:58.677 DEBUG 20816 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.c.ConfigFileApplicationListener  : Skipped config file 'classpath:/config/application.yaml' resource not found
2014-12-22 19:22:58.678 DEBUG 20816 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.c.ConfigFileApplicationListener  : Skipped config file 'classpath:/config/application.properties' resource not found
2014-12-22 19:22:58.679 DEBUG 20816 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.c.ConfigFileApplicationListener  : Skipped config file 'classpath:/config/application.yml' resource not found
2014-12-22 19:22:58.679 DEBUG 20816 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.c.ConfigFileApplicationListener  : Skipped config file 'classpath:/application.yaml' resource not found
2014-12-22 19:22:58.680 DEBUG 20816 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.c.ConfigFileApplicationListener  : Loaded config file 'classpath:/application.properties'
2014-12-22 19:22:58.681 DEBUG 20816 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.c.ConfigFileApplicationListener  : Skipped config file 'classpath:/application.yml' resource not found
2014-12-22 19:22:58.693  INFO 20816 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@ddd51a7: startup date [Mon Dec 22 19:22:58 EST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
2014-12-22 19:22:58.708 DEBUG 20816 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Bean factory for org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@ddd51a7: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@47649f10: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,main]; root of factory hierarchy
2014-12-22 19:23:00.964  INFO 20816 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'beanNameViewResolver': replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.class]]
2014-12-22 19:23:02.480 DEBUG 20816 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Unable to locate MessageSource with name 'messageSource': using default [org.springframework.context.support.DelegatingMessageSource@177df6c1]
2014-12-22 19:23:02.481 DEBUG 20816 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Using ApplicationEventMulticaster [org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster@4ed304f3]
2014-12-22 19:23:03.647 DEBUG 20816 --- [           main] .t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory : Code archive: /root/spectrom-upload-service/target/upload-service-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
2014-12-22 19:23:03.648 DEBUG 20816 --- [           main] .t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory : Code archive: /root/spectrom-upload-service/target/upload-service-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
2014-12-22 19:23:03.648 DEBUG 20816 --- [           main] .t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory : None of the document roots [src/main/webapp, public, static] point to a directory and will be ignored.
2014-12-22 19:23:03.691  INFO 20816 --- [           main] .t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory : Server initialized with port: 8080
2014-12-22 19:23:04.855  INFO 20816 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2014-12-22 19:23:04.856  INFO 20816 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.57
2014-12-22 19:23:05.008  INFO 20816 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2014-12-22 19:23:05.009  INFO 20816 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 6326 ms
2014-12-22 19:23:06.928  INFO 20816 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.e.ServletRegistrationBean        : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2014-12-22 19:23:06.933  INFO 20816 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
```

**After the ^c:**

```
^C2014-12-22 19:24:28.771  INFO 20816 --- [       Thread-2] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@ddd51a7: startup date [Mon Dec 22 19:22:58 EST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
2014-12-22 19:24:28.815  WARN 20816 --- [       Thread-2] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context close

java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@ddd51a7: startup date [Mon Dec 22 19:22:58 EST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getLifecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicationContext.java:359)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:890)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.doClose(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:141)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext$1.run(AbstractApplicationContext.java:811)
```

**Thread Dump during hang:**

```
2014-12-23 01:09:58
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.25-b02 mixed mode):

"localhost-startStop-1" #13 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f56c431a800 nid=0x12 runnable [0x00007f56e0bec000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:246)
    at sun.security.provider.SeedGenerator$URLSeedGenerator.getSeedBytes(SeedGenerator.java:539)
    at sun.security.provider.SeedGenerator.generateSeed(SeedGenerator.java:144)
    at sun.security.provider.SecureRandom$SeederHolder.<clinit>(SecureRandom.java:203)
    at sun.security.provider.SecureRandom.engineNextBytes(SecureRandom.java:221)
    - locked <0x00000000f10478f8> (a sun.security.provider.SecureRandom)
    at java.security.SecureRandom.nextBytes(SecureRandom.java:457)
    - locked <0x00000000f1047c18> (a java.security.SecureRandom)
    at java.security.SecureRandom.next(SecureRandom.java:480)
    at java.util.Random.nextInt(Random.java:329)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator.createSecureRandom(SessionIdGenerator.java:246)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator.getRandomBytes(SessionIdGenerator.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator.generateSessionId(SessionIdGenerator.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase.startInternal(ManagerBase.java:573)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.startInternal(StandardManager.java:485)
    - locked <0x00000000f0fa82e0> (a org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    - locked <0x00000000f0fa82e0> (a org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5501)
    - locked <0x00000000f68e5d68> (a org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedContext)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    - locked <0x00000000f68e5d68> (a org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedContext)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"Tomcat-startStop-1" #12 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f56c8405000 nid=0x11 waiting on condition [0x00007f56f4103000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000f69aa980> (a java.util.concurrent.FutureTask)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.awaitDone(FutureTask.java:429)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
    - locked <0x00000000f68505c0> (a org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:816)
    - locked <0x00000000f68505c0> (a org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    - locked <0x00000000f68505c0> (a org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"DestroyJavaVM" #10 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f56f0009800 nid=0x7 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"main" #9 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f56f0159800 nid=0x10 waiting on condition [0x00007f56f4cf0000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000f69aac08> (a java.util.concurrent.FutureTask)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.awaitDone(FutureTask.java:429)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
    - locked <0x00000000f68d1648> (a org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
    - locked <0x00000000f68d1648> (a org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    - locked <0x00000000f68d1648> (a org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    - locked <0x00000000f68d1648> (a org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    - locked <0x00000000f6850418> (a org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:739)
    - locked <0x00000000f6850590> (a [Lorg.apache.catalina.Service;)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    - locked <0x00000000f683f5d8> (a org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:341)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:85)
    - locked <0x00000000f68c4660> (a org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.<init>(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:74)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:377)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:153)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:148)
    - locked <0x00000000f5dd9708> (a org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:121)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:476)
    - locked <0x00000000f5de2550> (a java.lang.Object)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:109)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:952)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:941)
    at com.spectrom.uploadService.Main.main(Main.java:17)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:53)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"Service Thread" #7 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f56f00cd000 nid=0xe runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C1 CompilerThread1" #6 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f56f00ca000 nid=0xd waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread0" #5 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f56f00c8000 nid=0xc waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Signal Dispatcher" #4 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f56f00c6000 nid=0xb waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Finalizer" #3 daemon prio=8 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f56f009a000 nid=0xa in Object.wait() [0x00007f56f5500000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000000f5bb8068> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:142)
    - locked <0x00000000f5bb8068> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:158)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:209)

"Reference Handler" #2 daemon prio=10 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f56f0097800 nid=0x9 in Object.wait() [0x00007f56f5601000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000000f5bb8220> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:157)
    - locked <0x00000000f5bb8220> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)

"VM Thread" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f56f0090800 nid=0x8 runnable

"VM Periodic Task Thread" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f56f00dc800 nid=0xf waiting on condition

JNI global references: 29

Heap
 def new generation   total 13696K, used 12232K [0x00000000f0600000, 0x00000000f14d0000, 0x00000000f5950000)
  eden space 12224K,  88% used [0x00000000f0600000, 0x00000000f1082050, 0x00000000f11f0000)
  from space 1472K, 100% used [0x00000000f11f0000, 0x00000000f1360000, 0x00000000f1360000)
  to   space 1472K,   0% used [0x00000000f1360000, 0x00000000f1360000, 0x00000000f14d0000)
 tenured generation   total 30240K, used 20916K [0x00000000f5950000, 0x00000000f76d8000, 0x0000000100000000)
   the space 30240K,  69% used [0x00000000f5950000, 0x00000000f6dbd1b0, 0x00000000f6dbd200, 0x00000000f76d8000)
 Metaspace       used 23431K, capacity 23620K, committed 23728K, reserved 1071104K
  class space    used 2909K, capacity 2974K, committed 2992K, reserved 1048576K
```

Comment: What happens if you launch with `--debug`?

Comment: Debug is too big for pastebin, but the same results. All the debug prints are printed directly before what I've pasted above, and everything down from there is identical. Nothing of interest in the debugs that I've found so far. Is there a specific regions of the debug you're interested in? The whole thing is too big to paste at once.

Comment: Got it to fit: Debug logs are here http://pastebin.com/1HFk4YFR

Comment: I meant `--debug` for the Java launch, not the VM startup. I think you'd add that to the Dockerfile.

Comment: @chrylis I've swapped out the old logs for the debug logs

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Got it! Once I installed `haveged` on the host, the process immediately moved forward, and spring booted fine. I will post more once I do a bit more research into how docker interacts with `haveged` on the host.

In summary the following command issued on the host will fix the the issue:

```
apt-get install haveged -y
```

**If anyone has a detailed understanding of this, feel free to post!**

The thing that I don't understand at the moment, is why the host machine needed extra code, and everything wasn't isolated within the docker container.

Comment: Your containers have to share entropy with each other and with the host. Here's an article explaining some of what's going on: http://blog.pivotal.io/cloud-foundry-pivotal/features/challenges-with-randomness-in-multi-tenant-linux-container-platforms.

Comment: It is problems like this that remind us how insanely cool and complex what we do really is. +1

Comment: Just kinda curious how you figured this out? Saved me so much time

Comment: @Maleck13 I've written a quick post that walks through my sloppy thought process. In a week or two it should have some interesting details about entropy and docker, or link to a post that does. Check it out: http://scott.quine.io/2015/05/10/when-dev-random-fights-back.html

Comment: This can happen to you on a kvm based debian host as well, thanks!

Comment: Updated link to the blog referred by @DaveSyer - https://content.pivotal.io/blog/challenges-with-randomness-in-multi-tenant-linux-container-platforms

Comment: Halleluja, praise the lord!

Answer (score 20):

For those who might come here later. I think easiest solution is to modify Dockerfile and have entry point as follows:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["java", **"-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom"**,"-jar","app.jar"]
```

Had experience with apps hanging anywhere between 30 seconds and 15 minutes (or maybe more, but got killed).

From the other post that shares details:

Without this, Java uses `/dev/random` to seed its `SecureRandom` class, which can cause Java code to block unexpectedly.

Alternatively, in the `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/java.security` configuration file, add the line

```
securerandom.source=file:/dev/./urandom
```

Footnote: In the above examples, you need the crazy-looking filename, e.g., the extra `/./`, to trick Java into accepting your filename. If you just use /dev/urandom, Java decides you didn't really mean it and replaces what you wrote with /dev/random. Craziness!

Comment: I think this is a better solution for containerized approach. Else, you may need to make sure haveged is installed in the container, and hence modification of the Dockerfile may be required.

Comment: However, I am not sure if this setting is acceptable for production grade.