# Improve Spring-Boot startup in Docker

Tags: performance, docker, spring-boot

Approximately for standalone start as java process :

```
java -jar myspring_boot.jar
```

it takes around 20 seconds. But if I run it in a docker container which contain more micro services it takes around 3 minutes. 
Is there a way to speed up the spring-boot boot time as for an example
if I enable debug longing I notice that there are a lot of unnecessary validations for different spring configurations.
How I can speed up the spring-boot startup time only for dev purpose using Docker containers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I installed haveged daemon as it says in many answers out there, for example:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39461346/2748325

And also added -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=128m to my java CMD in the Dockerfile and the times went down in about 2 minutes.