# How to set system property for a service in ubuntu (spring boot application)?

Tags: spring, ubuntu, properties, spring-boot, system

My goal is to register an application, which is developed with Spring Boot 1.3.3, as a service on Ubuntu 14.04. Because of this issue [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25660899/spring-boot-actuator-application-wont-start-on-ubuntu-vps) I have to pass a system property `-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom` to the jar. If I only start the jar with java `-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom` -jar app.jar it works fine, but I don't know how to pass this property to this jar as a service?

I tried already to pass the property through application.properties and while maven package build process -> it does not help, my application does not start completely, it stops at this point:

```
2016-03-25 11:24:23 INFO  FilterRegistrationBean:258 - Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
```

My question is, how can I solve my problem? I do not want to change the java.security file, because it failed last time and I had to reinstall java8 :-/

Comment: Are you using Boot's support for building a fully-executable jar that can be run as a service?

Comment: yes, I do. For others, the Problem is solved, I installed (as proposed in linked Question) haveged, and it works now.