# Spring boot app hangs

Tags: ubuntu, spring-boot, cloud-foundry, swisscomdev

In the last couple of days I noticed that I have trouble starting my spring boot app. It always hangs at FilterRegistrationBean.

To solve this I have to restart the app multiple times after suddenly it starts.

Any ideas?

```
2016-05-30 15:01:50 [APP/0] OUT 2016-05-30 13:01:50.914 INFO 16 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean : Mapping filter: 'applicationContextIdFilter' to: [/*]
2016-05-30 15:04:42 [CELL/0] ERR Timed out after 3m0s: health check never passed.
2016-05-30 15:04:42 [CELL/0] OUT Exit status 0
```

Sample app:
https://github.com/gabac/swisscom-spring-boot-sample

Comment: A link to a sample project that illustrates this problem would allow us to debug it.

Comment: Try taking a thread dump while it's hung. You may be hitting this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25660899/spring-boot-actuator-application-wont-start-on-ubuntu-vps

Comment: @punkrocker27ka I've added a sample app https://github.com/gabac/swisscom-spring-boot-sample

Comment: @gabac I ran the sample application for a while and didn't encounter the hanging issue.  Have you tried running it on different hardware?  Either on premises or in the cloud?  Let me know if you can reproduce the issue in other environments.

Comment: @punkrocker27ka Locally it works without any issues. I only experience the hang during the startup in the Swisscom Cloud. There is no hang or so as soon as I got the app up and running

Comment: @gabac In that case it sounds environment related.  Make sure your cloud server has adequate resources.  Another thing to try would be to containerize your app and then test it locally & in the cloud.  That should help make the virtual environment more consistent.  See this guide for more detail: https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-docker/