# ERROR o.s.test.context.TestContextManager - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener

Tags: spring, ubuntu, spring-boot, spring-test

In my Spring Boot 1.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT application I'm  faced a following issue when run a tests at my Ubuntu server(locally everything work fine):

```
ERROR o.s.test.context.TestContextManager - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.AutoConfigureReportTestExecutionListener@3b0090a4] to prepare test instance [com.example.api.controller.v1.index.IndexControllerTest@3af9c5b7]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.AutoConfigureReportTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(AutoConfigureReportTestExecutionListener.java:49)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:68)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot instantiate interface org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextInitializer : org.springframework.boot.context.ConfigurationWarningsApplicationContextInitializer
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:422)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:401)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:392)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.initialize(SpringApplication.java:261)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>(SpringApplication.java:237)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.getSpringApplication(SpringBootContextLoader.java:121)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:84)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    ... 30 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class org.springframework.boot.context.ConfigurationWarningsApplicationContextInitializer is not assignable to interface org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextInitializer
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isAssignable(Assert.java:376)
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isAssignable(Assert.java:359)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:415)
    ... 38 common frames omitted
```

What can be a reason of this issue ?

**UPDATED**

Finally I have started my application with an additional VM argument `-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom` as described in this question [Spring Boot Actuator application won't start on Ubuntu VPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25660899/spring-boot-actuator-application-wont-start-on-ubuntu-vps) but still no luck with my tests on this Ubuntu server

Comment: `ConfigurationWarningsApplicationContextInitializer` implements `ApplicationContextInitializer` so it should be assignable. The fact that it's not suggests that you must have some classloader problems with two different versions of `ApplicationContextInitializer` on the classpath. It's impossible to say what the reason for that might be without some more information. Perhaps you can share a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](/help/mcve)?

Comment: Finally I have started my application with additional VM argument `-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom` as described in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25660899/spring-boot-actuator-application-wont-start-on-ubuntu-vps but still no luck with my tests on this Ubuntu server