# Spring Boot Jar does not deploy on ubuntu 16.x

Tags: java, deployment, spring-boot, ubuntu-16.04

I have a spring boot web app(with embedded tomcat) and It works fine on my windows pc. However, when I put the mvn packaged jar file to my ubuntu server, It takes forever to deploy the application. There is no error message, it is just waiting on mapping stage of deployment. The latests outputs are below.

```
2016-09-25 15:23:19.852  INFO 16780 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2016-09-25 15:23:19.854  INFO 16780 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 11342 ms
2016-09-25 15:23:20.456  INFO 16780 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2016-09-25 15:23:20.458  INFO 16780 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2016-09-25 15:23:20.459  INFO 16780 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2016-09-25 15:23:20.459  INFO 16780 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2016-09-25 15:23:20.466  INFO 16780 --- [ost-startStop-1] .s.DelegatingFilterProxyRegistrationBean : Mapping filter: 'springSecurityFilterChain' to: [/*]
2016-09-25 15:23:20.468  INFO 16780 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
```

I also tried to re-package whole project on my ubuntu server and the result was same.

**EDIT: LOGS**

```
2016-09-25 22:55:53.554 DEBUG 18207 --- [main] o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment     : Adding [servletConfigInitParams] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
```

2016-09-25 22:55:53.593 DEBUG 18207 --- [main] o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment     : Adding [servletContextInitParams] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2016-09-25 22:55:53.599 DEBUG 18207 --- [main] o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment     : Adding [systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2016-09-25 22:55:53.602 DEBUG 18207 --- [main] o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment     : Adding [systemEnvironment] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2016-09-25 22:55:53.604 DEBUG 18207 --- [main] o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment     : Initialized StandardServletEnvironment with PropertySources [servletConfigInitParams,servletContextInitParams,systemProperties,systemEnvironment]
2016-09-25 22:55:59.776 DEBUG 18207 --- [main] o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment     : Adding [applicationConfig: [classpath:/application.properties]] PropertySource with search precedence immediately lower than [applicationConfigurationProperties]
2016-09-25 22:55:59.783 DEBUG 18207 --- [main] o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment     : Removing [applicationConfigurationProperties] PropertySource
2016-09-25 22:55:59.783 DEBUG 18207 --- [main] o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment     : Removing [defaultProperties] PropertySource
2016-09-25 22:56:06.859 DEBUG 18207 --- [localhost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Published root WebApplicationContext as ServletContext attribute with name [org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext.ROOT]
2016-09-25 22:56:06.861  INFO 18207 --- [localhost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 12666 ms
2016-09-25 22:56:07.360 DEBUG 18207 --- [localhost-startStop-1] o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment     : Adding [servletConfigInitParams] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2016-09-25 22:56:07.366 DEBUG 18207 --- [localhost-startStop-1] o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment     : Adding [servletContextInitParams] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2016-09-25 22:56:07.374 DEBUG 18207 --- [localhost-startStop-1] o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment     : Adding [systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2016-09-25 22:56:07.376 DEBUG 18207 --- [localhost-startStop-1] o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment     : Adding [systemEnvironment] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2016-09-25 22:56:07.376 DEBUG 18207 --- [localhost-startStop-1] o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment     : Initialized StandardServletEnvironment with PropertySources [servletConfigInitParams,servletContextInitParams,systemProperties,systemEnvironment]
2016-09-25 22:56:07.423 DEBUG 18207 --- [localhost-startStop-1] o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment     : Adding [servletConfigInitParams] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2016-09-25 22:56:07.431 DEBUG 18207 --- [localhost-startStop-1] o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment     : Adding [servletContextInitParams] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2016-09-25 22:56:07.432 DEBUG 18207 --- [localhost-startStop-1] o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment     : Adding [systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2016-09-25 22:56:07.433 DEBUG 18207 --- [localhost-startStop-1] o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment     : Adding [systemEnvironment] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2016-09-25 22:56:07.434 DEBUG 18207 --- [localhost-startStop-1] o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment     : Initialized StandardServletEnvironment with PropertySources [servletConfigInitParams,servletContextInitParams,systemProperties,systemEnvironment]
2016-09-25 22:56:07.470 DEBUG 18207 --- [localhost-startStop-1] o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment     : Adding [servletConfigInitParams] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2016-09-25 22:56:07.470 DEBUG 18207 --- [localhost-startStop-1] o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment     : Adding [servletContextInitParams] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2016-09-25 22:56:07.471 DEBUG 18207 --- [localhost-startStop-1] o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment     : Adding [systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2016-09-25 22:56:07.473 DEBUG 18207 --- [localhost-startStop-1] o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment     : Adding [systemEnvironment] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2016-09-25 22:56:07.473 DEBUG 18207 --- [localhost-startStop-1] o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment     : Initialized StandardServletEnvironment with PropertySources [servletConfigInitParams,servletContextInitParams,systemProperties,systemEnvironment]
2016-09-25 22:56:07.527 DEBUG 18207 --- [localhost-startStop-1] o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment     : Adding [servletConfigInitParams] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2016-09-25 22:56:07.528 DEBUG 18207 --- [localhost-startStop-1] o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment     : Adding [servletContextInitParams] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2016-09-25 22:56:07.528 DEBUG 18207 --- [localhost-startStop-1] o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment     : Adding [systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2016-09-25 22:56:07.528 DEBUG 18207 --- [localhost-startStop-1] o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment     : Adding [systemEnvironment] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2016-09-25 22:56:07.528 DEBUG 18207 --- [localhost-startStop-1] o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment     : Initialized StandardServletEnvironment with PropertySources [servletConfigInitParams,servletContextInitParams,systemProperties,systemEnvironment]
2016-09-25 22:56:07.583 DEBUG 18207 --- [localhost-startStop-1] o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment     : Adding [servletConfigInitParams] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2016-09-25 22:56:07.583 DEBUG 18207 --- [localhost-startStop-1] o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment     : Adding [servletContextInitParams] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2016-09-25 22:56:07.584 DEBUG 18207 --- [localhost-startStop-1] o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment     : Adding [systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2016-09-25 22:56:07.584 DEBUG 18207 --- [localhost-startStop-1] o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment     : Adding [systemEnvironment] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
2016-09-25 22:56:07.585 DEBUG 18207 --- [localhost-startStop-1] o.s.w.c.s.StandardServletEnvironment     : Initialized StandardServletEnvironment with PropertySources [servletConfigInitParams,servletContextInitParams,systemProperties,systemEnvironment]

Comment: Turn up the logging?

Comment: Take a thread dump when it's stuck. I suspect your question's a duplicate of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25660899/spring-boot-actuator-application-wont-start-on-ubuntu-vps/25669300#25669300)

Comment: Thank you very much Andy. It is absolute dublicate :) and the solution is there.

Comment: Question is dublicate and can be closed. Solution is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25660899/spring-boot-actuator-application-wont-start-on-ubuntu-vps/25669300#25669300)